# Карьера программиста

Tags: работа

Можно ли после 9 класса поступить на программиста?

Comment: Можно, в колледж, но не нужно.
Лучше сразу в институт после 11 класса.

Comment: @yuridik, сейчас самое лучшее время для свободного плавания - когда реально варишься только в том, что интересно, при этом нет никаких рамок и требований закончить что-то к какому-то числу. Играйтесь с чем нравится, вам это потом сыграет на руку и при поступлении, и в самом университете.

Comment: Подписался на вопрос. А то тоже неохота оставаться до 11-го класса.

Comment: @yuridik, @SuperCreeper а чего вдруг так приперло-то? Пользы от окончания школы после девятого класса вы уж наверняка не получите. В России сейчас и высшее образование не на высоте, а уж про всякие там колледжи-техникумы говорить и вовсе не приходится, особенно если учиться по каким-либо айтишным специальностям

Comment: А какая будет польза от окончания школы после одинадцатого класса?  Буду знать ещё несколько каких-нибудь замороченных формул/правил, которые мне в жизни не пригодятся. Неужели после девятого некуда податься?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, парочка фрмул?... А ты уверен что ты учишься, а не ходишь для галочки? С таким отношением карьеру максимум менеджера по продажам построишь)

Comment: @SuperCreeper, на вскидку:
После 11 класса открывается дорога сразу в институт на получение высшего образования. Как правило в пути получения образования "колледж-высшее" длиннее на 1-2 года(4+6), чем 11 класс-высшее(2+6). Еще два года более-менее свободного времени, по сравнению с колледжем, которое можно потратить на подготовку. В колледже пойдет сжато тот же самый курс 10-11 класса. Уровень конечных знаний колледжа по стандартным программам обучения довольно низок и может так выйти, что программистом стажером и то Вас не возьмут.

Comment: @DreamChild *пушо Билл Гейтс и Стив Джобс отчислились и все равно сделали карьеру!111 Зачем учиться если я будущий стив джобс.*

Comment: @Fike ну да, только Биллов Гейтсов и Стивов Джобсов - один человек на миллиард, и было бы несколько неразумно ставить себя любимого на одну доску с ними. Да и Россия к сожалению далеко не США, у нас биллы гейтсы (ну или брины, если уж точнее) уезжают за рубеж и основывают там Google, вспоминая потом Россию как Нигерию в снегах. Sad but true

Comment: Надо же, как молодеет IT-поколение... Раньше великие умы области колледжи бросали, а теперь школы...

Comment: Спасибо всем, что объяснили!) Наверно я всё-таки уйду после девятого и буду каким-нибудь электриком/дворником, но программирование оставлю как хобби.

P.S. Вторым Стивом Джобсом я становится не планирую.  
[P.P.S.](http://m.imgur.com/uEjoMnr)

Comment: даже успешные программисты, получающие хорошие зп, продолжают учиться всю жизнь. и образование не ограничивается алгоритмами и кодированием. разностороннее образование развивает человека как личность и выгодно отличает от быдла. это приятно и полезно.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, ну зачем так сразу серьезно в дворники. Мы ведем речь исключительно об образовании как таковом, не учитывая того факта, что человек может заниматься самообразованием и саморазвитием, а так же получить откуда-то практические знания. Если присутствуют эти факторы, то это намного лучше, чем получить корочку простым отсиживанием за партой и с таки же успехом стать никем. ВУЗ дает основы, но стать программистом вы должны сами своим трудом.

Answer (score 6):

Если у Вас неоконченное среднее образование, о котором идет речь, то Вы можете поступить в колледж и получить среднее-специальное образование. В технических колледжах подготовкой по квалификации "техник – программист" занимается специальность "230115 Программирование в компьютерных системах".

К сожалению в институт берут только на базе полного среднего образования (11 классов) или средне-специального, поэтому туда поступить не получится.

Перед принятием решения все же лучше хорошо подумать, может стоит остаться в школе и доучится до полного среднего образования. А так же помнить, что образование в учреждениях не сделают Вас полноценным программистом, им даже можно(и наверное нужно) вполне стать без этого, если приложить достаточно усилий по самообразованию.

P.S. Ответ без сторонних размышление по существу

Answer (score 5):

[@yuridik](/users/18412/yuridik), вряд ли хоть один нормальный работодатель возьмет школьника.

Так что, продолжайте учиться. И имейте в виду, что с вузовской корочкой шансы найти приличную работу  выше, чем без нее.

А исключения лишь подтверждают правило (именно поэтому их и называют исключениями).

Answer (score 4):

Не рекомендую. Сам учусь в колледже на программиста, но я пошел на базе 11 классов. К сожалению баллов не хватило в ВУЗ.
В колледжах очень слабая база для программистов. То с какими знаниями уходят студенты из техникумов и колледжей это то что они сами изучили или скромный багаж который кое как затолкали преподаватели. Сейчас у нас в колледже 3-4 более менее нормальных программиста которые пойдут по специальности. И это то из 4 групп.
Так что решайте сами)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы стать программистом не обязательно куда-либо поступать.

Comment: но желательно для будущей карьеры, если не планируешь всю жизнь заниматься мелким фрилансом

Comment: Нет. Примеров в истории миллион.

Comment: Хотя после того как еще раз хорошо подумал - да, наличие образования это плюс. Но повторюсь это не обязательное условие.

Answer (score 2):

вобщем доучивайся до 11 класса, параллельно изучай основу программирования, базовые приёмы, циклы, алгоритмы, и т.п.

после 11 класса идёшь на платные курсы порядка 6 месяцев, потом устраиваешься как Junior с окладом 500-1000 $

дальше строишь карьеру 1000$ - 10000$

всё просто.

Comment: не хватает только копипасты про питон и хайлоад

Comment: @Fike, Доставлено!  
Завтра ищешь в интернете книжку Dive into python. По... если ничего не поймешь. Затем идешь на python.org и изучаешь стандартную библиотеку от корки до корки. Потом зубришь, именно, с..a, вызубриваешь конвенцию по написанию питоньего кода - PEP8, чтобы от зубов отскакивало. Когда напишешь свою первую имиджборду, по пути изучив верстку на html+css, скачиваешь и изучаешь любой питоний асинхронный вебсервер, рекомендую Tornado или Gevent.

Comment: Как переделаешь имиджборду, чтобы выдавала по крайней мере 5 тысяч запросов в секунду, можешь идти дальше - тебя ждет увлекательный мир хайлоада. Apache Hadoop, сверхбыстрые асинхронные key-value хранилища, MapReduce. Отсос хиккующих вы....ков / просто неудачников типа рейфага или сисярп/джава-...сосов, которые сосут ... по жизни не заставит себя ждать и уже через пол года ты будешь получать такие суммы, что любая баба будет течь при одном упоминании твоей зарплаты.

Comment: @SuperCreeper  ну ты и расписал... разве в деле главное зарплата? Я вот в пятницу отказался от места, где получал бы почти в два раза больше, хотя я сейчас получаю достаточно хорошо.

Comment: И второе,я сишник,и могу сказать, что проекты, в которых я работаю, на порядок интереснее, чем ты тут описываешь золотые горы.

Comment: Это копипаста.

Comment: @akalend, вы уверены, что нам нужно знать про вашу зарплату?

Comment: @Etki я что, зарплатой хвастаюсь? или пальцы в растопырку держу?

Answer (score 2):

Чтоб стать программистом, не обязательно какое-либо образование, но желательно для HR. Я лично знал пару хороших WEB-программистов-школьников (уже выросли). Один из них написал известный в WEB кругах проект: PHPDaemon. Второй сейчас работает в IBM. Вспомним про www.chatruletka.ru, который сделал Московский 11-ти классник... А ведь он не проходил каких-либо крутых курсов.

Теперь об образовании: к сожалению оно у нас больше для корочки. Наличие образования (высшего) - это не показатель хорошего программиста. Это больше показатель способности доводить что-то до конца(например сдать сессию), в какой-то мере показатель IQ.

Есть вузы, где учат индустрии программного обеспечения хорошо (МФТИ, МИФИ ЛИТМО Институт Криптографии ФСБ), есть где поверхностно. Что дает техникум? - максимум научат основам Алгоритмов и выучишь один из языков программирования. На практике этого явно мало. Нужно знать основы работ РСУБД, специфику конкретных БД, NoSQL, алгоритмы сбора и анализа данных, понятие отладки и тестирования приложений. Если специализация WEB, то 
 - знание стека сетевых технологий
 - особенности настроек разных HTTP серверов
 - HTML5, CSS, JS, AJAX и так далее
 - автоматизации тестирования
 - разные фреймворки 
и многое и многое ...

Если специализация по компьютерным играм и графики, то знание аналитической геометрии просто необходимо, особенности алгоритмов триангуляции и рендеринга, разные прикладные библиотеки OpenGL,OpenCV, особенности видеокарт и их программирования и т.д,
В общем это те знания, о которых не учат в колледже.

Теперь о главном, как жить дальше? Как стать программистом? Лично я - больше самоучка. Программирование было у меня на первом курсе и очень поверхностно.
В настоящее время существует очень много хороших программ: Участие в Олимпиадах,  Google Code-in, ориентированный на школьников, заинтересованных в участии в Open Source-проектах (в этом году наш школьник занял первое место), Участие в разных образовательных проектах Microsoft. Участие в летнем лагере программистов при ЛЭТИ(или ЛИТМО). 
В общем как проявить себя на раннем этапе становления - море.

Самый лучший путь становления - это участие в OpenSource проектах.